Error when running npm run android in visual studio
When executing the npm run android command it gives me the following error
Error: The system cannot find the specified path.
Error: The system cannot find the specified path.
    at notFoundError (C:\Users\joyca\OneDrive\Desktop\practices\AppDeliveryReactNative\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:6:26)
    at verifyENOENT (C:\Users\joyca\OneDrive\Desktop\practices\AppDeliveryReactNative\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:40:16)
    at ChildProcess.cp.emit (C:\Users\joyca\OneDrive\Desktop\practices\AppDeliveryReactNative\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:27:25)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:294:12)

